# Dynamic mass table update in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, multiple-tables

I need to preform the following update from user_table_a to user_table_b. It seems much harder than I though, so I think I'm missing something regarding syntax. These are the table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE user_table_a (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(255),
    points INT(11)
);

CREATE TABLE user_table_b (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(255),
    score INT(11),
    user_table_a_id INT(11)
);
```

A user is the same person in both tables as identified by their email value. Emails are unique to the system. In user_table_b the `user_table_a_id` field is newly added, and is currently empty. Using email as the link between these two tables I want to update the correct value of each user_table_a id into the corresponding place in user_table_b. I know this can be done by leveraging php or a stored procedure, but I am trying to do this without those things. This is my failed query thus far:

```
# this fails because the subquery returns more than one record and ...
# because a subquery cannot reference the table being update in the main query
UPDATE user_table_b SET user_table_a_id = (SELECT user_table_a.id FROM user_table_a, user_table_b WHERE user_table_a.email = user_table_b.user_email GROUP BY user_table_a.id) WHERE 1;
```

I'm not sure if what I am trying is possible, I will continue to research. Thank you to anyone who helps.

Comment: Note your second table is called user_table_a also, instead of user_table_b.

Comment: @HamzaKubba Indeed, xQbert beat me to it. Good catch guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE user_table_b b SET user_table_a_id = (SELECT a.id FROM user_table_a a WHERE a.email = b.email);
```

Comment: This should work, though note that a subquery is much slower than a join.

Comment: I used a limit clause in the subquery in the final version. Thanks for showing me this. This is a powerful tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an inner join with the update. This should work (let me know if not):

```
UPDATE user_table_b utb 
    INNER JOIN user_table_a uta
    ON uta.email = utb.email
    SET utb.user_table_a_id = uta.id;
```